# Concatenating mysql_query in C

Tags: mysql, sql, c

I am getting user input from my C program and I want to use the user input in my SELECT statement. However the mysql_query() only has accepts two parameters. I was thinking of coding it like this... `mysql_query(con, "SELECT discontinued FROM products WHERE productid = '$products'", products_product_id)` however I know that I will get error messages. What would be the best way to tackle this?

```
int products_product_id;
                
printf("-----------------\n");
printf("ADDING AN ORDER\n");
printf("-----------------\n");

scanf("%d", &products_product_id);
while(products_product_id <= 0 || products_product_id >= 78)
{
        printf("ProductID not found. Try again.\n");
        scanf("%d", &products_product_id);
}
                
printf("Searching for: %s\n",products_product_id);
                
if (mysql_query(con, "SELECT discontinued FROM products WHERE productid = '%products_product_id'", products_product_id) 
{
        dberror(con);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-query.html) takes two arguments while you pass in 3.  Use [mysql_bind_param](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-bind-param.html) to bind variables to your query.